# Excel is pausing my word doc each time it refreshes the link between the tables that I have in excel and my word doc

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a word doc with many linked excel tables in it.  Every so often, word has to pause while the excel automatically refreshes it.  How can I slow down the intervals between refreshing to say once an hour?

Comment: Is the Word doc being refreshed because the Excel file is changing/updating?

Comment: My guess is that this is caused by the AutoSave feature in Excel.  You can set this to every 60 minutes and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options but updating the data every hour is not one of them.

**Option 1:** *Change the `Update method for selected link` to manual:*

- Right click on the linked Excel spreadsheet > Linked Worksheet Object > Links
- Click on Manual update
- Whenever you need to update the data, right on linked Excel, then select `Update Link`

[image]

[image: Manual update]

**Option 2:** *Do not update when opening Word doc*

- File > Options > Advanced
- Under General header, uncheck `Update automatic links at open`

[image]

[General resource on linking vs embedding.](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Link-or-embed-an-Excel-worksheet-41bf021e-ba7c-44ef-9914-0d7e88062257?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bm2)